# Does a subsequence in a tree certificate guarantees it contains given tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, isomorphism

I am using an algorithm for tree certificates described for example [here (p. 24-29)](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/13966764/computing-isomorphism-ch7-kreher-stinson-ch3-kaski-).

Let's say I have two trees: **A** and **B**, and each tree has it's certificate produced by the algorithm above (**C1** and **C2**).

Is it true, that if **C1** contains **C2** (exact sequence anywhere), it means **A** contains **B** as a subtree (**B** can be basically concentrated and considered as a leaf node of **A**)? If not, could you state a counter-example?

--edit--

**Algorithm: (please take a look at the linked document for examples):**

1. Label all vertices with string 01
2. While there are more than 2 vertices in G:

   for each non-leaf x do:

   1. let Y be the set of labels of the leaves adjacent to X and the label of x with initial 0 and trailing 1 deleted from x.
   2. Replace the label of x with the concentration of the labels in Y, sorted in increasing lexicographic orher, with a 0 prepended and a 1 appended.
   3. Remove all leaves adjacent to x.
3. If there is only one vertex x left, report x's label as the certificate.
4. If there are 2 vertices x and y left, concentrate x and y in increasing lexicographic order, and report it as the cerfificate.

Comment: Could you please include inside the question the relevant parts of the referenced document?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, page (or slide) 24-29

Comment: I mean: *inside* the question, embedded. Questions will stay here for many years to come. Links can break.

Comment: ok, edited as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

Assuming the certificate is correct, there is no possibility a certificate would contain another certificate and it wouldn't be it's subtree.